# how to handle directive from another directive angular 6

Tags: angular, onclicklistener, directive

- Hi everyone !. I have an issue with directive in angular 6. I have directive add class to element when i clicked on this and i want remove it when i click on another element or click outside. Please see attached images

```js
import { Directive, HostBinding, HostListener  } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[expandMenu]'
})
export class ExpandMenuDirective {

  constructor() { }

  @HostBinding('class.active') isOpen = false;
  @HostListener('click') toggleOpen($event){
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }
}
```

Comment: is the click event working? have you tried a blur event to handle the click outside?

Comment: when i clicked on element it work well , but when i click another element i want remove class of before element

Comment: Please see image http://prntscr.com/kz7up3

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture clicking outside you should use `blur`, however if you are using it on `div` that never works since the div content is not editable.

But there is a workaround. Let's say this is your directive:

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[classHandler]',
  host: {
    '(click)':'_setInputFocus(true)',
    '(blur)':'_setInputFocus(false)',
    '[class.md-input-focus]':'inputFocusClass'
  }
})

export class ClassHandler {
  inputFocusClass: boolean = false;

  _setInputFocus(isFocus: boolean) {
    this.inputFocusClass = isFocus;
  }
}
```

And now you are using this on a div or your menu item:

```
<div classHandler>This is a placeholder</div>
```

This will not work, but if you add `tabindex="1"`, then it will work:

```
<div tabindex="1" classHandler>This is a placeholder</div>
```

I believe this will solve your issue. You can have a [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnrh5r?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html).